# You need to make the object collider ignore the same as they are

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a unity game, I have enemies that have to go through all objects except themselves. That is, I set a "*Is Trigger = true*" for them, and they easily fly through all the objects, but they also collect in a heap over time and it’s not clear how many enemies fly after me. 
I know about such a method as "*Physics2D.IgnoreCollision()*", but I can not find a normal explanation of how it works.
In general, you need to teach objects to ignore the same as them.

Comment: Have you looked at the collision matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Unity's layers and collision matrix.

Assign the enemies to a layer named `Enemy`
To do this, select the Enemy GameObject (or prefab) and click Layer > Add Layer

[image]

Type `Enemy` into User Layer 8 or any blank slot
[image]

Go back to the Enemy GameObject/prefab, click Layer > Enemy

Change the collision matrix to ignore collisions between enemies:

Go to Edit>Project Settings>Physics and uncheck the Enemy > Enemy checkbox in your collision matrix (see image for example collision matrix)

[image: collision matrix example]

Comment: You could also use tags :D

Comment: @jakeisthecoolest I don't think tags are considered in the collision matrix